# Is website MUST to publish android app?

Tags: android

Almost all android apps have links to 'developer's website'. Typically websites are used in assigning name spaces.

How can I assign unique package namespace if I don't have any website?
Or to put it other words, is website a parameter in assigning the namespace

If yes, can you please guide me how to get own site?

Dharma

Comment: If by namespace you mean the [package](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package), then no, a website is not required to publish an app to Google Play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace is just that, a namespace. There is no need to create or own your own domain. You just need to be sure that your namespace is reasonable unique.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need any website at all, package system is as the following:
If your package name is com.dharma.app then eclipse will generate a folder system like "src\com\dharma\app\". So, in the src(sources) folder, the outer folder will be com, 1 level deeper dharma, 1 level deeper app. Hope you understand it this way.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to name your packages following the java package naming convention. Following this article:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

This is recommended but not mandatory. i.e. you can just use an appropriate namespace without actually owning the domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some other method of uniquely identifying your apps if you do not have a web domain name to use. Domain name is the recommmended way, but for example an email address or some other package name can be used as well depending on how important it is for you to distinguish your app as one made by a company.